# ksh function return value in parentheses

Tags: linux, bash, function, shell, ksh

In the following very simple ksh script example, I need to ask if func1 results equal to 4 ,

This is what I did in the example but this script does not print the "function result = 4" as I expected it to.

What do I need to change in the [[......]] in order to print the  "function result = 4"

Remark - func1 must be in the [[.....]]

```
  #!/bin/ksh

  func1()
  {
    return 4
  }

  [[ ` func1 ` = ` echo $? `  ]]  && print "function result = 4"
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need

```
#!/bin/ksh

  func1()
  {
    print -- 4
  }

  [[ $(func1) = 4  ]]  && print "function result = 4"
```

OR

```
#!/bin/ksh

  func1()
  {
    return 4
  }

  func1 ; [[ $? == 4 ]]  && print "function result = 4"
```

There are several issues in the code that you present, so let me try to explain (You're making it more complicated than it need be).

No. 1 is your use of back-ticks for command substitution, these have been deprecated in the ksh language since ~ 1995! Use $( ... cmd ) for modern cmd-substitution. We often see backticks listed as a nod to portability, but only scripts written for systems where the Bourne shell is the **only** shell available require the use of backticks. (well, I don't know about dash or ash, so maybe those too).

No 2. is that $? gets set after ever function or command or pipeline is executed and is the return code of that last command. It is a value between 0-255. When you have code like `cmd ; rc=$? ; echo $?` ; you're now echoing the status of the assignment of `rc=$?` (which will almost always be 0), AND that is why you will see experienced scriptors save the value of $? before doing anything else with it.

Recall that command-substitution uses what ever is the output of the `$( ... cmd ...)` or backtics enclosed command while `return` sets the value of `$?` (until **the very next command execution** resets that value).

I hope this helps.

Comment: tnx @JaypalSingh ; In my testing for writing my answer I also stumbled on the issue that [[ func1 = 4 ]] was not getting the return value from the function. I now realise, as per a comment now deleted, that `[[ ... ]]` will only evaluate text values, + comparison ops + command-substitution (maybe others too), but no way to directly execute a func inside.

Comment: Yea, @ruakh pointed that out in my answer which I deleted as I had it all wrong. But now reading your answer and his comment, it makes alot more sense now.

Comment: I also UPVOTE for you nice explanation

Answer (score 4):

Function does return 4. The operator `` (backticks) ignores the result value, and returns the function's stdout instead (in your case an empty string, since func1 did not print anything to stdout).

And

```
`echo $?`
```

is just over-complicated way of saying

```
$?
```